# Conditional formatting - my code is not rendered and directly reflected in the output in MS WORD

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I am trying to apply conditional formatting to merge fields on MS Word. I want the bold text when `scode` = Total.

So I added a mergefield, pressed alt+f9 together, updated the field like below. Note that I've used ctrl + f9 to create curly bracket blocks.

`{ IF { MERGEFIELD scode } = "Total" **{ MERGEFIELD scode }** { MERGEFIELD scode }` }

My problem is, the code doesn't get rendered for some reason and the output is like:

```
 { IF 500 = "Total" **500** 500 }

 { IF 600 = "Total" **600** 600 }

 { IF Total = "Total" **Total** Total}
```

So the code itself comes to the output file. Expected output is:

```
500

600

**Total**
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your fields look a bit whacky. What is "Total?" Is it a bookmark? I'm not sure what the bare numbers are going to do when compared to text. Try attaching a link to a sample document and explaining what it is you are trying to accomplish.  ----  BTW, Excel is much better at this than Word.

Comment: Here is an excellent tutorial on Mail Merge; http://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html

Comment: Can you provide your document sample about the fields?